# Build timeout after 00:15:00 minutes because of Testimpact

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, msbuild, timeout

Recently I keep getting this error from our Build server. If we turn off the TestImpact this error won't appear. We like to see what impact our tests have so I'm looking for another solution. Does anyone know what this means? I can't find anything about it!

> **Exception Message: The http request operation timed out after 00:15:00. (type TimeoutException)** Exception Stack Trace: at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpRetryChannel.Request(TfsMessage message, TimeSpan timeout) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpClientBase.Invoke(TfsClientOperation operation, Object[] parameters, TimeSpan timeout, Object[]& outputs) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestImpact.Client.TestImpactServer.Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestImpact.Client.ITestImpactServer.PublishBuildChanges(Uri buildUri, CodeChange[] changes) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestImpact.BuildIntegration.BuildActivities.GetImpactedTests.Execute(CodeActivityContext context) at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager) at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

Comment: Have you find a solution? I am having the same issue.

Comment: Still no solution right? I have been trying to fix this for months without success, so I have started a bounty on this. Maybe there is an away to increase the timeout period. I cannot live without this, since I have more than 6000 automated tests, which may be impossible to run all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may have found what seems to fix the issue. This is what I did and since them it is working:

1. I used Team Foundation Sidekick to delete all the workspaces that were created by the user that is used to build the application, and also old workspaces that were not used anymore by developers. It seems that the number of workspaces affect the build system.
2. I have set the "Clean Workspace" to false on all my build definitions, so it wont create a new workspace every time a build is fired.
3. I have disabled the Test Impact and ran a build. The Test Impact needs to have a baseline build to start with. After the build finished I activated the Test Impact again.
4. I have moved the drop location of the builds to another HD to speed up the build (because of the disk IO). Builds occur in one HD and the drop is set to another one.

Now it seems to be working so far. Maybe these steps will work for you as it worked for me. But I do need more time to make sure it is working.

Answer (score 1):

I think Rafael Colucci has answered your question only partially.

> The Test Impact needs to have a baseline build to start with.

and below error suggest the same

```
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestImpact.Client.TestImpactServer.Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestImpact.Client.ITestImpactServer.PublishBuildChanges(Uri buildUri, CodeChange[] changes) at
```

Also according to my knowledge Test Impact needs to have a previous build to be present. So it can calculate the impact upon code change.

I think disabling the clean build may solve your problem. Let us know what result you are getting.

Comment: Mm.. That should make sense indeed. I'm gonna try it out! Thanks